# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.04

I am trying to build a [LIBS](http://www.tcllab.org/canasai/software/libs/libs-0.1.4.tar.gz) from the Thai Computational Linguistics Laboratory from source.

I am following the instructions as per their readme, which states

```
2. Installation
---------------

2.1) In the libs base directory, type:

$ ./configure
$ make
```

However, ld complains about 'cannot find -ll'.

```
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../..  -W -Wall -I../../src/libs   -g -O2 -MT libs-predict.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/libs-predict.Tpo" -c -o libs-predict.o libs-predict.c; \
        then mv -f ".deps/libs-predict.Tpo" ".deps/libs-predict.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/libs-predict.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
mode=link g++  -g -O2  -o libs-predict  libs-predict.o -L../../src/libs -llibs -lm -ll
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: [libs-predict] Error 1 (ignored)
```

What library is this and what package do I need to install to have it?

Comment: can you post the steps you're taking to do this build?  That sure looks like a command line switch mistakenly taken as a command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library [libl.a](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/lex_library.htm) is classically the support library for AT&T Lex - it provides a dummy version of `yywrap()` and `main()`, and some other support functions.  If you are using [Flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/I-get-an-error-about-undefined-yywrap_0028_0029_002e.html), then I don't think any library is needed - the code is self-contained (as long as you provide your own version of `yywrap`; if you don't, use `-lfl`).  So, you probably just need to arrange to remove the '`-ll`' from the command line.

If that is too hard, then create yourself a file `garbage.c` containing:

```
int podunk = 0;
```

Compile it to `garbage.o` and create a dummy `libl.a`:

```
gcc -c garbage.c
ar r libl.a garbage.o
```

The linker should pick up this dummy library, find nothing of relevance in it, and continue its merry way onwards.

Answer (score 3):

while compiling lex yacc programs... if you get this error...

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then Solution for this is :

```
dnf install flex bison
dnf install flex-devel bison-devel
```

Comment: thanks.  your answer led me to what I think is the ubuntu equivalent: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70525465/5203563

Answer (score 1):

What if you run `$(which ld)` (using command substitution, or you can use backticks in place of `$(…)`) instead of just `ld`?

If that helps, then type in `alias -p` and see if you have an alias set for the `ld` command which is causing the `-ll` switch to be sent.

Comment: I'm not calling ld directly, that's make at work. I've updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: take a look at line 189 of "src/libs-cmd/Makefile". Maybe you can modify the command there to make it work.

Comment: I've gone and removed the -ll, and that seems to work.